# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found

Tags: hibernate

I am executing a hibernate query. It produces the error below. When the query is executed from SQL workbench it produces the expected result.

```
List<Object[]> studentResult = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        String queryStudentResult = "select sd.student_id,sd.name,sd.email_address,sd.phone_number,sd.dob,sd.gender ,st.test_score,CAST(st.test_score AS DECIMAL(4,2))/CAST(st.total_max_score AS DECIMAL(4,2))*100 AS testscore,std.percentage,std.college_name,std.college_city,std.college_state,rd.Degree,rb.branch_Name,se.10_percentage,se.12_percentage " + 
                " from student_details sd " + 
                "inner join student_test_completion st on sd.student_id=st.student_id " + 
                "inner join student_login sl on sl.student_id=sd.student_id " + 
                "inner join test_details td on td.test_id =sl.test_id  " + 
                "inner join category c on c.category_id =td.category_id  " + 
                "inner join student_degree_details std on std.stu_degree_id = (select stu_degree_id  from student_degree_details where  student_id= st.student_id LIMIT 1 ) " + 
                "inner join registration_degree rd on rd.Degree_ID= std.degree " + 
                "inner join registration_branch rb on rb.branch_Id= std.branch " + 
                "inner join student_education se on se.student_id=sd.student_id  " + 
                "where CAST(st.date_of_test as date) between ? and ? and st.college_name=?  " + 
                "and c.category_name='Assessment' and std.isCurrent_degree=1 ";
        Object[] queryParam = {date1,date2,testdetails.getCollege_name()};

        studentResult = template.find(queryStudentResult, queryParam);
```

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '('
>   near line 1, column 124 [select
>   sd.student_id,sd.name,sd.email_address,sd.phone_number,sd.dob,sd.gender
>   ,st.test_score,CAST(st.test_score AS
>   DECIMAL(4,2))/CAST(st.total_max_score AS DECIMAL(4,2))*100 AS
>   testscore,std.percentage,std.college_name,std.college_city,std.college_state,rd.Degree,rb.branch_Name,se.10_percentage,se.12_percentage
>   from student_details sd inner join student_test_completion st on
>   sd.student_id=st.student_id inner join student_login sl on
>   sl.student_id=sd.student_id inner join test_details td on td.test_id
>   =sl.test_id  inner join category c on c.category_id =td.category_id  inner join student_degree_details std on std.stu_degree_id = (select
>   stu_degree_id  from student_degree_details where  student_id=
>   st.student_id LIMIT 1 ) inner join registration_degree rd on
>   rd.Degree_ID= std.degree inner join registration_branch rb on
>   rb.branch_Id= std.branch inner join student_education se on
>   se.student_id=sd.student_id  where CAST(st.date_of_test as date)
>   between ? and ? and st.college_name=?  and
>   c.category_name='Assessment' and std.isCurrent_degree=1 ]     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)

Comment: can you try big_decimal instead of decimal since you are using HQL. Check the documentation. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic

Comment: Hibernate template.find method not supporting to run case and function . I have implemented using session.createsqlquery. Now it is working as expected